# Coding Landscape mode: Is there an inspector for iOS simulator?

Tags: html, ios, css, wordpress, landscape

I'm coding a fully responsive cross-browser site. I've already coded portrait mode and what I did to inspect changes and modify the my CSS file was to scale my Chrome Browser up to a point where I saw the same thing on my browser and on my iOS simulator. In that way I could work out every change and edit my CSS file. I now need to do the same on landscape mode, but I can't find a way to use an inspector that would simulate landscape mode.

I have Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE and I'm open to any tool that would enable me to inspect the webpage simulating landscape mode not only regular tablets and phones but also Retina-supported devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a really cool plugin. 
http://lab.maltewassermann.com/viewport-resizer/

You can use it on any browser. Drag the "Click or Bookmark" button to your bookmark bar, then click it on any page you want to change the view size for.

Here is the image of the button you want to drag to your bookmark bar:
[image: button you need to bookmark]

Here is an image of the toolbar that it adds.
[image: toolbar]

My favorite tool to use for this is http://www.browserstack.com/. This isn't free but well worth it.

A third option is [Adobe Edge Inspect](http://html.adobe.com/edge/inspect/). You can display the page right on the device but inspect the elements through you laptop or desktop computer. This option is free but you need to create an Adobe ID.

Comment: Once I get to the site and select a specific setup,  where should I put the web page I need to emulate?

Comment: After adding the bookmark to your toolbar you simply view the page you want to test, then click the resizer bookmark. It then will resize the site you are viewing and a menu bar at the top will be added.

Comment: @Streck, I've just went through each of them, but I still can't inspect my webpage in landscape mode on a retina revice. I can view how it renders in the virtual machines that browserstack offer, but the software won't allow me to inspect the elements (what I need to make my coding faster). What I'm doing now is modifying and reloading my iOS simulator each time to see how changes are going, but it's taking me more than I expected.

Comment: I have added a third option in my answer > Adobe Edge Inspect. You'll need to install it on both your computer and tablet. Also DPI doesn't matter in web development. set viewport meta width to device-width. Something like this <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">

Comment: @Gonpires, did my answer solve your problem? If so please accept it as the correct answer